# Passing string array to powershell function doesn't work as expected

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell. Why does the array get mangled (seems like it gets concatenated???) when passed to the function `test`? I have no idea what's going on. Works OK if the function only has one parameter, but adding a second parameter makes it act up. I've tried googling, but can't come up with the right terms.

```
function test([string[]] $arrInFn, [boolean] $something) {
    Write-Host "Array length in function: $($arrInFn.Length)"
}

$arr = @()
$arr += "test"
$arr += "another entry"
$arr += "third entry"
Write-Host "------------------ TEST OUTPUT-------------------"
Write-Host "Array length inline: $($arr.Length)"
test $arr, $true
```

[image: Test Output][image: Updated Test Output]

Comment: Parenthesis are not used when calling functions in Powershel: `test $arr, $true`

Comment: OK, fixed, but it still fails with the same output

Comment: Woops, I was slacking. Get rid of the comma in the call as well.

Comment: OH ... this is going to take some getting used to. That did the trick. Thanks

Comment: To add to EBGreen's comment. You can call each parameter like this as well: `test -arrInfn $arr -something $true`

Comment: If you add that as an answer, I'll accept

Comment: That other question is not a perfect dupe but it is essentially the right answer and would have solved your problem.

Comment: Close enough. Not sure why I didn't find it before